# Using apply() on class method

Tags: class, ecmascript-6, apply

Is it possible to call the apply() method on a class method? I am currently receiving a undefined value. I am looking for the output to read "Todd is the father of Jason, Karla, and David".

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  set name(newValue) {
    this._name = newValue;
  }
  info() {
    return this._name + " is the father of " + children;
  }
}

var children = ["Jason ", " Karla", " and David"];

var e1 = new Person("Todd");

var ref = e1.info.apply(e1.name, children)

document.querySelector(".test").innerHTML = ref;
```

Comment: You can call `.apply()` on a class method, but you HAVE to pass it an appropriate value for `this` (the first argument to `.apply()`).  It does not appear you are passing it a `Person` object as the `this` argument when you are using it.

Comment: when I console.log(e1.name) I receive “Todd”.

Comment: Thats a string, not a Person object.

Comment: Why are you even trying .apply here.  Just use `e1.info()`

Comment: I realize I can use e1.info() but I’m learning to use call(), apply() and bind() because I’ll need to know how moving forward with JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `.apply()`, you need to pass two arguments to it.  The first is the object that you want to call the method on.  In your case above, that would be `e1`.  The second argument is an array of arguments you want passed to the method.

So, you could do:

```
var ref = e1.info.apply(e1, children);
```

But, your `info` method isn't really right.  If you're going to pass arguments to `info()` with `.apply()`, then you should probably use those arguments and the way it's written now, it's trying to add a global array to a string which isn't right for several reasons.

Perhaps you want info to be this:

```
info(...args) {
   return this._name + " is the father of " + args.join(",");
}
```